# I need help in doing the partitions for the installation process

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, usb-drive

So,i'm in the middle of the OS installation,and in the part where i should be able to choose the drive where i install it it wont let me choose the one where windows 10 is.

It just shows  another one i have that is empty.

So the only way i can manage to use the drive where windows is,is trough the manual partitioning method.
The thing i want to do is pretty straight forward,i want to install elementary in my os drive (270 gb of free space approx) and let my other drive (500 gb of free space) be available for both os for storing several data.

Is it possible and how should i go about doing it?
Or can anyone lead me to a guide for doing it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to create a new partition on your os drive. You can shrink your Windows partition using the Disks Management Tool that comes on Windows. 
Then just leave the empty space you want for elementary. You need 10 GiB at least, but I'd recommend to have 30 Gib or more to have some extra space to install programs.

Now Reboot, then plug your elementary OS bootlable USB and install it. You can also go into advanced settings on Windows 8-10 and select "reboot and boot from usb".

After that, when you reach the partitioning stage you should be able to format that empty space and create a new Ext4 partition. Just set it as `/` so that elementary OS is installed there. If you have less than 8 Gib of RAM you should also create a SWAP partition of the same size as your RAM.

Comment: Thanks,i allocated 20gb for the OS and went with the "install alongside windows 10" option.So far the only problem i have is that windows wont boot trough grub,i have to sort the boot options in the bios so i can use windows.I know this is no chat platform,but do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Hmm.. try this:  from Linux open a terminal and `sudo update-grub` then reboot and check if there's a windows 10 option. If that didn't work, install and run boot-repair : https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair

Comment: to install it: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update && sudo apt install boot-repair` 

I don't usually recommend adding PPAs but this is gonna be the fastest way to do it so...

If the first command didn't work, install this as well: `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`

Comment: Thanks,at the end all i had to do was run boot-repair and it was fixed.